# Where to store config variable in angular 2.0 like client credentials for API

Tags: rest, api, angular

Where can I store Client Credentials When an app is consuming a API in Angular 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

I never store the user's password, but once the user has logged in and received an authentication token, I put it in [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) (`sessionStorage` or `localStorage`)

This will allow the credential to survive as users refresh the page, or browse away and then later come back.

If you're responsible for back-end authentication, be sure to enforce token expiration and beware of [other pitfalls](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet).